# Changing the location of the emacs server socket

Tags: server, daemon, emacs-daemon

When I run `emacs --daemon` it creates a socket at `/tmp/emacs1000/server`

How can I tell it to use a different location?

Comment: The only thing I managed to find is changing the name of the file it uses, by giving the daemon a name. I didn't notice anything of potential interest in `server.el`, and there is a chance this is just hard-coded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directory where the socket is created is controlled by this variable:

```
(defvar server-socket-dir
  (and (featurep 'make-network-process '(:family local))
   (format "%s/emacs%d" (or (getenv "TMPDIR") "/tmp") (user-uid)))
  "The directory in which to place the server socket.
  If local sockets are not supported, this is nil.")
```

If you use tcp sockets (probably not a good idea), the variable is `server-auth-dir` with value `~/.emacs.d/server/`.

The name of the socket is the name of the server, as @DoMiNeLa10 notes in a comment, and can be changed by customizing the value of the variable `server-name`.